# changing the key value separator in an ini file

Tags: java, ini4j

I have an ini file with `||` as the key value separator. I want to parse it using ini4j library but it is giving me an error (exception) whenever I run the code. I think that ini4j identifies only `=` and `:` as key-value separators. Is there any other way I could parse the file while using ini4j?

this is my example file

```
[header]
one||1
two||2

[section1] 
three||3
four||4
five||5
six||6

[section2]
seven||7
eight||8
nine||9
```

this is my example code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Ini ini=new Ini(new File("/home/esunmes/NetBeansProjects/ini4jexample/src/ini4jexample/newfile2.ini"));
    for(String str:ini.keySet())
    {System.out.println(str);
     Ini.Section section=ini.get(str);
     for(String key:section.keySet())
     {System.out.println("the key is : "+key);// TODO code application logic here
}
```

}

I also want to know the case :key||value1||value2

Comment: What does the Exception say? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: what if i wanna do it periodically for a large no. of logs?

Comment: Using Java 6 or Java 7? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: Please post details. You said you are getting an exception, post the stacktrace and the exception details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing your delimeter with the expected `=`?

```
    String inputPropties = "KEY1||VALUE1\nKEY2||VALUE2\nKEY3||VALUE3";
    inputPropties = inputPropties.replaceAll("\\|\\|","=");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new StringReader(inputPropties));
    for( String key: properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        System.out.println(key+" = "+properties.getProperty(key));
    }
```